# Windows Notification from node service from electron

Tags: node.js, service, electron, node-windows, node-notifier

I can send windows notification from electron using `node-notifier`

```
notifier.notify({
    appName: "myapp",
    title: 'My notification',
    message: 'Hello, there!'
  });
```

I can run service from electron using `node-windows`

from my main process

```
var svc = new Service({
    name: 'MyService',
    description: '',
    script: 'MyService.js',
  });
svc.on('install', function () {
    console.log('Install complete.');
    svc.start();
  });
svc.install();
```

But when I try to send notification from a service that was created from electron doesn't shows up. Although I checked that code inside the service is ran without any error in the log!

I know this is possible in c# but how do I do that in electron?

Any guide how can I send notification from a service?

Thanks

Comment: *I can send windows notification from electron using node-notifier* - how did you do that? *I can run service from electron using node-windows* - how did you do that? *But when I try to send notification from a service that was created from electron doesn't shows up.* - how did you do that? The question requires https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Are you on windows 10 or windows 8?

Comment: Windows 10 @Mike

Answer (score 2):

Try to use build in electron notification, document here:  https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/notifications.
In case you tried it but it doesn't work, you must miss this:

> On Windows 10, a shortcut to your app with an Application User Model ID must be installed to the Start Menu.

You must set AppID in main process, just put this line in main: `app.setAppUserModelId('yourappid')`

Hope this helps

Comment: That seems to be working, I tried wil both electron's notification and node-notifer. No notification shows up after setting appid